# how to modify my SharePoint2013 web URL?

Tags: 2013, url

I'm here again =)

I have the following url: `http://servername:7050/site/subsite/Pages/default.aspx`

I would remove the "Pages" and have a custom url like this: `http://servername:7050/site/subsite/default.aspx`

I searched some sites and I saw that in sharepoint 2013 is this possible, but I have not found where. 
Can anyone help me?

Comment: search for Managed Metadata Navigation in SharePoint 2013 or Friendly Urls with Managed Metadata Navigation.. Google is your friend :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your looking for term based navigation:

goto site settings -> look and feel -> click on navigation

for both global and current select managed navigation

now goto term store managment tool

> 1.From the site collection Home page, click Site Contents
>
> 2.On the Site Contents page, click Settings.
>
> 3.On the Site Settings page, in the Site Administration group, click Term store management.

click on the page you want ammending, image below is what you need todo to make it friendly! what your looking for is Term-driven pages :)

[image]

more info here:

https://habaneroconsulting.com/insights/Term-based-navigation-in-SharePoint-2013